# AWS S3 action policy CLI vs Console to paste objects in one bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I created a policy:

```
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": "s3:*",
"Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
    "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
]
```

and the users of the policy can use the CLI to move objects within the specified bucket. However, they couldn't use the Console to move (copy/cut then paste) objects within the bucket. They always had error "access denied" when trying to paste objects.

After taking out actions one by one, I figured out that `GetBucketLocation` and `ListAllMyBuckets` for all buckets (`arn:aws:s3:::*`) are required in order to copy-paste/cut-paste inside one single bucket. So, adding the actions below work:

```
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": [
  "s3:GetBucketLocation",
  "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
],
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
```

My question is: why the CLI doesn't need the 2 actions to allow users move objects within one bucket but the Console requires them?

Comment: Sorry, but are you asking a question, or just wanting to provide some useful information to other readers? If it is just useful information, please create an Answer to your own question with that information, and remove it from the Question. Or, if you are asking a question, could you please clarify what is your actual question?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm asking if anyone knows or understands why the AWS console requires the 2 specific actions in order to do the paste operation whilst the CLI doesn't require them. I'm going to edit my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

It would be because the Amazon S3 console calls those particular APIs.

It probably calls `GetBucketLocation` because AWS API calls need to be sent to the region that contains the destination bucket, so it needs to know the region of the target bucket.

It calls `ListAllMyBuckets` when it displays the complete list of buckets. It is strange that it would require those permissions when *within* a particular bucket. It should only be needing it when going to the 'home page' of the S3 console, not specifically when copying an object.

The AWS CLI, of course, does not list buckets so it wouldn't call `ListAllMyBuckets`.

You can use **AWS CloudTrail** to view the API calls made to your AWS Account, including those by the console and the AWS CLI.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll check that. The users had to use the URL to go straight to the bucket in the Console (with a web browser) so I don't understand why it requires those actions.